# Modify a variable before it saves to database

Tags: forms, hooks

I have a user profile form.  I'm having trouble modifying a variable before it saves to the database.  I have these hooks in my template.php but the value going into my database is still the same value that was submitted in the form post.

```
function mytheme_user_profile_form_presave()
{
  if($form['#id'] == 'user-profile-form') {
    if($_POST)
    {
            $ec = 'fooo';
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $ec;
            form_set_value($form['field_last_name'],array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $foo))),$form_state);

    }
  }
    return '';
}

function mytheme_preprocess_user_profile_form()
{
  if($form['#id'] == 'user-profile-form') {
    if($_POST)
    {
            $ec = 'fooo';
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $ec;
            form_set_value($form['field_last_name'],array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $foo))),$form_state);

    }
  }
    return '';
}

function mytheme_user_profile_form_validate()
{
  if($form['#id'] == 'user-profile-form') {
    if($_POST)
    {
            $ec = 'fooo';
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value']['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = $ec;
            $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['#entity']->field_last_name['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $ec;
            form_set_value($form['field_last_name'],array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $foo))),$form_state);

    }
  }
    return '';
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

UPDATE

Ok, I added this in my template.php

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'user-profile-form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_foo_data';
  }
}
```

Then I added this to `mymodule.module`

```
function mymodule_foo_data(&$form,&$form_state)
{

        $form['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value'] = 'foo';
}
```

The function mymodule_foo_data gets fired on save.  But the value foo doesn't get written to my database.  Instead, the value that's in the $_POST array is what gets written to the database.  how do I get foo into the databasE?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is the best. You need to do the following:

1. Add a custom module.
2. Implement hook_form_alter in your module and and alter the user
   profile form. Form id: `user-profile-form`.
3. Add a validation function i. e. `$form['#validate'][] =
   'my_module_custom_form_validate';`.
4. add an implementation for the function in your module and modify the form values as you wish.

Also, you don't need to use the `$_POST` variable if you are following the drupal form api.

Comment: thanks i was able to get `my_module_custom_form_validate` to fire.  However, the values are going straight into my database without the field modifications I intended.  I added my small bits of code showing this in my question.

Comment: You should alter `$form_state` not `$form`. Inside validate handlers you should use [form_set_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) to alter the `$form_state`